# Agatha RRSL and StructureMap 3.0

Tags: structuremap, agatha-rrsl

I want to use Agatha RRSL with my implementation of the StructureMap 3.0 wrapper to Agatha's IoC container. Agatha has NuGet packages with StructureMap 2.6 which I do not like.

I started by copy/pasting the code from Agatha.StructureMap [source code](https://github.com/davybrion/Agatha/blob/master/Agatha.StructureMap/Container.cs) and proceeded to make the changes to use 3.0 StructureMap.

The issue I now have is that I get a StructureMapException

```
StructureMap.StructureMapBuildPlanException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message=Unable to create a build plan for concrete type Agatha.Common.WCF.RequestProcessorProxy
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Unable to create a build plan for concrete type Agatha.Common.WCF.RequestProcessorProxy

new RequestProcessorProxy(InstanceContext, String endpointConfigurationName, String remoteAddress)
  ┗ InstanceContext = **Default**
                  String endpointConfigurationName = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined
                  String remoteAddress = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined



  Source=StructureMap
  Context=new RequestProcessorProxy(InstanceContext, String endpointConfigurationName, String remoteAddress)
  ┗ InstanceContext = **Default**
                  String endpointConfigurationName = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined
                  String remoteAddress = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined

  Title=Unable to create a build plan for concrete type Agatha.Common.WCF.RequestProcessorProxy
  StackTrace:
       at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.ToBuilder(Type pluginType, Policies policies) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorInstance.cs:line 83
  InnerException:
```

This looks to me as though the constructor StructureMap thinks it needs to use, but views as not properly configured, is the one with multiple parameters. In reality I need it to use the parameterless constructor.

However I think I've configured the constructor properly. Here is the code I use to configure a parameterless constructor for RequestProcessorProxy:

```
 structureMapContainer.Configure(x => x.ForConcreteType<RequestProcessorProxy>().Configure.SelectConstructor(() => new RequestProcessorProxy()));
```

What may have gone wrong?

Just as heads up, I'm new to both StructureMap and Agatha so I may have misunderstood any or all of the above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used `SelectConstructor` so don't know how to make it working with it but if you want to make SM to use parameterless constructor then you can do it like this when you resolve concrete type:

```
var container =
    new Container(
        c => c.For<RequestProcessorProxy>().Use(() => new RequestProcessorProxy()));
```

or like this when you are resolving it by the interface:

```
var container =
    new Container(
        c => c.For<IRequestProcessor>().Use(() => new RequestProcessorProxy()));
```

I am not familiar with Agatha RRSL at all so I don't know whether I used good interface.

Hope this helps!